# VBA/MS SQL equivalent to SAS Retain function

Tags: vba, sas, retain

Is there a VBA/MS SQL equivalent to SAS Retain function.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question should be refined to explain your purpose better.  VBA and MS-SQL are two different worlds. In VBA, the keyword `Static` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

First, `retain` in SAS is not a function, it's a statement.

Second, the idea behind it - to persist the value of a variable across iterations of the implicit loop in a SAS data step - only makes sense as a statement in that context.

You can achieve the same end in a variety of languages in a variety of ways. Pretty much all languages enable you to explicitly create a loop and iterate through rows of data, and pretty much all languages allow you to store a variable's value alongside this loop and retrieve it and conditionally change it. In VBA this is pretty rudimentary: you would declare a variable, assign it a value and reference it however and whenever you want throughout code that loops through data.

In SQL, you're dealing in sets, so there is no real equivalent to retain because you're not looping sequentially through rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

`RETAIN` in SAS is telling SAS *not* to do something - ie, set a variable missing between iterations of the implicit data step loop.  So VBA already does this.

```
for x = 1 to 5
...
next x
```

None of the variables there get set to missing.

Pure SQL is a bit different, since it's not really order-based programming.  But it also does not set a variable missing between iterations of an implicit loop - but I imagine you know that.

If you mean 'is there a way to carry a value down for each row', well, sure:

```
update tablex set var1=6
```

OK, now tablex has var1 = 6 on every row.  That's not exactly the same as

```
data want;
set have;
retain var1;
var1=6;
run;
```

because the latter allows you to do something like

```
data want;
set have;
retain var1;
var1=var1+1;
run;
```

That's not really logical in SQL.  You can do things like that, depending on what flavor of SQL you are in and depending on actually what you want (for example, oracle has `rownum` similar to `_n_`), but SQL's inherent lack of consistent processing order means it tends to be much more complicated.